Система оплаты в приложении
Подскажите как можно сделать оплату товаров в приложении, android версия приложения будет добавляться в PlayMarket, а ios версия в AppStore. На последней странице оформления товара будет кнопка оплатить и она должна перенаправить на сайт оплаты. Какую систему оплаты можно использовать в связи с санкциями? И возможно ли использовать оплату через Сберабанк?

Идем на офф сайт и понимаем, что если не попадаем под исключения, то должны использовать платежную систему Google Play.
Далее смотрим изменения для РФ и видим, что для пользователей(не для разработчиков) из РФ можно отступать от правил. Т.е. если ваши пользователи из России или Беларуси, то можно использовать свою систему. Но если есть пользователи из других стран, то для них Google Play.
Обращаем внимание на последний абзац:

Ситуация быстро меняется, поэтому мы рекомендуем следить за новостями на этой странице. Ниже мы ответили на вопросы, которые могут возникнуть у разработчиков. Информация будет дополняться.

P.S: в таких ситуациях нужно читать официальную информацию. Какая разница, что вам тут напишут, если Гугл запретит вам использовать что-то. Вас тут могут надурить)
